# How to get a newly loaded image's width / naturalWidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose this html:

```
<img src="thumbnail/img.png">

<div class="frame">
</div>
```

Thumbnails lie in their own directory called `thumbnail`, while the regular size images they refer to are to be found in `regular`. The thumbnails are attached an event listener which behaves like this on click (being `e` the event passed as parameter):

```
var src = $(e.target).attr("src");
var path = "regular/" + src.slice(src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

So what I put into the variable `path` in this case is `regular/img.png`. Next I want `frame` to take the image at `path` as background and adapt its size to it, but something strange happens:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = path;

console.log(image.width); // weirdness starts here
                          // same behavior with .naturalWidth
```

I'd expect the console to show `image`'s width, but what I get is a `0`. ***Only at the first click though***: any further click yields the correct value.

**Why is that?**

Comment: It's because the image hasn't loaded yet when you call `width()`. You need to add a `load()` event handler to the `img` and get the width in there.

Comment: @Kaiido I haven't downvoted anything? What does this have to do with FBlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because the image hasn't loaded yet. You'll need to register an event listener like this before you set the "src" attribute (and not after, because as soon as you set the "src", it will start loading the file) and then do your stuff within the callback function:

```
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(image.width);
}, false);
image.src = path;
```

NOTE: This is plain javascript, and therefore does not rely on any external libraries; you could also use the jQuery `load` function, or something similar, to achieve the same effect, if you prefer.

Comment: I only used jQuery as the OPs first example was. Either of our answers will solve the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good point, it's always good to have more than one way of doing something!

Comment: I accepted this answer since it's good and points to Rory's answer as well, which is just as valuable.Thank you!